# PageSpeed Insights versus Core Web Vitals

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I have been working on improving the Core Web Vitals for a website and when I use PageSpeed Insights I consistently get scores in the upper 90s.  But when using Google Webmaster Tools the Core Web Vitals information shows that LCP and FID need improvements.  Does Google use different servers or locations to calculate this information when you run interactively versus what Webmaster Tools uses and reports? I also installed the Lighthouse extension for Chrome and this never shows issues.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand, why this was downvoted. This is still a problem imho. WMT says everything is perfect, while Pagespeed Insights shows that there are big problems (not the lab data!). Even "Core Web Vitals" in Chrome dev tools show different values than Insight's Lab Data (both should be live data). After all, I decided to trust WMT's report (which I believe is the data Google uses for ranking). Also, my page values like pages/view and bounce rate are absolutely fine, so I'll put extra work into content rather than over-optimization less important things (as long as WMT reports are good).

Answer (score 0):

Total score is not indication of web vital pass. As you know Pagespeed insight has 3 sections "Field Data", "Origin Data", "Lab Data" . "Origin Data" Will close match with Core Web Vitals report of google search page and "Field Data" for specific page.

Core web vital does not use any specific server etc it is field data what actual user are facing in the google chrome browser.   Ex:- You might be testing in 4g Internet & actual user might be using 3g. They will see slowness compared to you. Like that many variations.  To go little depth of web vital report use https://g.co/chromeuxdash  and report can help where you are getting bad scores and can apply fix there.

Thanks